# Flexbox: Move header and footer to sidebar with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My content layout consists of three sections: header, content and footer. For small devices I want to keep this order, on desktop I would like to move header and footer to the sidebar.

Implemented using floats: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqrZby

Markup

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

.page:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.page > * {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.top {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
}

.bottom {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .content {
    width: 66%;
    float: left;
  }
  .top, .bottom {
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to find a solution using flexbox with a fixed spacing between content and sidebar. Anybody got an idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the stucture and using flexbox you need to use `flex-direction:column`.

First we build it "*mobile first"* because it follows the actual order of the div structure we have already.

Then, at the appropriate media query we need to make the container wrap...often this will require a fixed height (be it viewport or px value)...then we can re-order the elements (using, ahem, `order`) and impose our required widths.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ONXQrW)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
}
.top {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
  order: 2;
}
.bottom {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  order: 3;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .page {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .top {
    order: 2;
  }
  .top,
  .bottom {
    width: 33%;
  }
  .content {
    order: 1;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 66%;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The wrap is the wall I've always hit. I can't set the page container to a fixed height. And I didn't find a way to force the wrap otherwise.

Comment: At the moment, well,until `display:contents` comes along (or at least is properly supported) this is the only option I'm aware of...for flexbox. Of course there is viewport units and max-heights to play with.

Comment: The html structure is actually not fixed. But I didn't see how another could help. But I will experiment with viewport units. Thanks!